# What is the Dlang standard streams module?

Tags: stream, d, standard-library

What is the Dlang standard streams module?

https://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_stream.html refers to https://github.com/dlang/phobos/blob/master/std/stream.d but this page at GitHub does not exist.

I guess, it is removed because of deprecation. What it is superseded with?

Comment: there isn't one really. crappy answer but the truth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the upcoming [`std.io`](https://github.com/MartinNowak/io) module. It is intended to provide a "thin, OS-independent abstractions over I/O devices".
Here's a short [example](https://github.com/MartinNowak/io/blob/master/src/std/io/package.d#L201) of this module.

There's also the more high-level [iopipe](https://github.com/schveiguy/iopipe) which uses the upcoming `std.io` module and provides a nice and efficient range API for I/O devices.

However, as D is becoming more popular and seeing more usage, the Phobos dev team got more concerned with the quality of the standard modules and thus the addition process got more rigid. In the meantime, dub (D's package manager) became the de-facto package manager for D and it got a lot easier to share new "standard modules" via dub (and having proper SemVer releases for them).

You might also be interested in Vibe.d (probably the best-known web framework for D), also it defines its own streaming functionality that can be used standalone from [`vibe-core`](https://github.com/vibe-d/vibe-core). See e.g. [`stream.d`](https://github.com/vibe-d/vibe-core/blob/master/source/vibe/core/stream.d) for details.

Last, but not least, `std.stream` is not fully gone yet and continues to live in [undeaD](https://github.com/dlang/undeaD/blob/master/src/undead/stream.d).